# Underbrace in equation

Tags: equations, underbrace

What is wrong with underbrace please, there is no text below after the compilation

```
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{{\color{red}I_j (x)} \ast \Delta_j(x,t_l,{\color{red}p})}_{\text{I_j(x)(x-v_j(t,p))}} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Unrelated, this will never work at `\text` switches to the text font where _ is not allowed. It ought to work if you remove the text command. And as mentioned, please always post full minimal examples, not sniplets.

Comment: ... Or probably related. (I tend to react heavily to bad usages of the text command as it is a **very** frequent issue that people does not realize)

Comment: Remove `\text` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\text` is when the subscript is textual.

You should also prefer `\textcolor` and brace the whole `\underbrace` construct.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 {% make the \underbrace an ordinary atom
  \underbrace{\textcolor{red}{I_j (x)} \ast \Delta_j(x,t_l,\textcolor{red}{p})}%
    _{I_j(x)(x-v_j(t,p))}
 }\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why preferring `\textcolor`? Because you can redefine it to preserve the nature of math atoms:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@textcolor}[3]{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    \begingroup\color#1{#2}#3\endgroup
  \else
    \protect\leavevmode{\color#1{#2}#3}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\textcolor{red}{=}b$

$a{\color{red}=}b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why `\textcolor{...}{...}` should be preferred over `{\color{...} ...}`?

Comment: @GuM `\textcolor` uses `\begingroup...\endgroup` rather than `{...}`, with obvious effects on the math list.

Comment: I didn’t know this.  Is it a new feature?  In version 2.12 (2016/05/11) of the `xcolor` package the definition of `\@textcolor#1#2#3` is still `\protect\leavevmode{\color#1{#2}#3}`.

Comment: @GuM I seemed to remember this feature. Anyway, it's easy to add it.

Comment: Well, as you say, `\begingrup ...\endgroup` is indeed better, for obvious reasons.  The same change should be made in the `color` package too.  The latter is currently maintained by “The LaTeX3 Project”, which includes you. :-)